# find big oh for "for loop that has method call"

Tags: java, big-o

I have tried to find the big oh for this code,

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i*=2)
fun(n);
```

where fun() is a method that has complexity of o(n^2)

and I figured that the `for`  statement has complexity of o(log n).
so, the big oh for all the code will be o(n^2logn).
am i right ?

Comment: I think that "for" statement has complexity of o(n)

Comment: Tell us why you think it's o(n^2logn). I don't think it is.

Comment: Yes,you are right, If the function is called inside forloop

Comment: @Victoria The for loop has complexity `logn` because `i=i*2` takes only log(n) steps to reach n

Comment: I don't think "for" statement has complexity of o(n), because the loop will not go for all indexes .so, it has to be something smaller than o(n). which is (log n)

Comment: Yes, the loop has the complexity o(log n) (because i*=2) and if fun(n) has o(n^2) the final complexity will be o(n^2log n)

Comment: Did you mean `for(int i=1;i<n;i*=2)`? Otherwise it's an infinite loop

Comment: @Eran taking into consideration that this was accepted, that was indeed `i = 0` :)

Comment: It would rather be `O(n^(2+logn))` because you multiply powers with the same base

Comment: @Eugene if it was indeed `i=0`, why he  just can not use `while (true)`?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod this was probably an assignment... to see how attentive users are, I guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is O(Infinite), because you initialise i to 0 and then multiply it by two each iteration.

Comment: since `i=0` it will be always less than `n`

Comment: @Eugene If `n` is 0 or negative, it won't even start the loop, but if `n` is a positive integer, _BarrySW19_ is indeed right. `i` is initialized as 0, and remains 0 every iteration, since `0 * 2 = 0`, so the `i<n` will always remain truthy.

Comment: @AndyTurner ))) oh shoot I though that was `i = 1`, damn... I really think it's a typo though

Comment: @Eugene not necessary. It could be a test, if you pay enough attention on details.